# Changing default stoarage

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, lenovo

I am a lenovo k3 note user.i was initially using android lollipop.Now i updated my phone to  android 6.0 marshmallow.Earlier in lollipop ,i was able to change my default storage in to SD card.But in marshmallow that option is not available.what should i do ??

Answer (score 0):

#### Marshamallow SDcards is Adoptable as an internal storage

Android has had limited support for removable storage in one form or another since the beginning. With Marshmallow, the new Adoptable storage feature lets you turn your removable SD card option into a more or less permanent (and no longer removable) part of the device.

The whole thing is simple, really, and most of the confusion surrounding Adoptable storage is easy to clear up. There are a few things to keep in mind so you understand how it works and what it's doing.

If you want to read more, visit [Android  Central](http://www.androidcentral.com/inside-marshmallow-adoptable-storage)